# Is JOIN operation possible in ElasticSearch using any ES Connector for presto or Hive (ElasticSearch-Hadoop)?

Tags: join, elasticsearch, hive, presto, elasticsearch-hadoop

As we know that JOIN operation is not possible in ElasticSearch among indices, Can it be achieved using Presto or Hive, i.e. can we do a JOIN operation using any ElasticSearch Connector for Presto or Hive ?

Can we do JOIN in ElasticSearch using ElasticSearch-Hadoop - https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if you write a connector for ElasticSearch to Presto, you can use it to do JOINs. JOINs in Presto are processed inside the core engine, and don't involve the connector, except to read the underlying data.

Comment: Has anybody written such a connector ? any links to help writing such a connector would help.

Comment: I don't know of an ElasticSearch connector, but take a look at the jdbc connector and the example http connector. They're both in the main presto repository

Answer (score 0):

There is a Hive [ElastiSearch connector](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/5.5/hive.html).

Presto can work over Hive metastore

**UPDATE**

This [doesn't work](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/7721)